# CSS editing angular2 datepicker doesn't work

Tags: angular, typescript, responsive-design, datepicker

I have started recently working with Angular2 datepicker. However, I cannot find out how to edit color/borders/font/etc of datepicker.

I inspected element of datepicker, used class="wc-date-container" and placed it in css file where i added those things, but it doesn't work.
Here are parts of my angular component.html and css files.

```
<angular2-date-picker
   [(ngModel)]="search.date_from"
   [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"
   [settings]="timeSettings" >
</angular2-date-picker>
```

```
.wc-date-container {
    border: 1px solid rgba(155, 151, 151, 0.911);;
}
.wc-date-container > span {
    color: rgba(155, 151, 151, 0.911);
}
.wc-date-container > i {
    font-size: 20px;
    color: rgba(155, 151, 151, 0.911);
}
```

Thank you very much for looking. I hope I didn't leave out some important detail.
I checked out other answers, but didn't find one that addresses this. I used parts of this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/solomon301/s3hL05s6/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Angular uses a *shadow DOM*, as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57906378/8038345).

The `datepicker` uses a custom component, so their css classes does not colide with your component's css (this is the [css encapsulation](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles)) .

What you can do is put the css classes in a global file, generally called `style.css`, in root folder.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40273463/angular-2-global-css-file) explains how to do it properly.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! However, when I placed css classes in styles.scss in root folder, and also placed styles.scss in angular.json, but nothing happens..

Comment: this is what my css class look like in styles.css: 
`.wc-date-container{
    border: 1px solid rgba(156, 153, 153, 0.644);
    background: #fff;
  }
  .wc-date-container > span{
    color: rgba(156, 153, 153, 0.644);
  }
  .wc-date-container > i{
    font-size: 20px;
    color: rgba(156, 153, 153, 0.644);
  } ` (i wanted to make my calendar looks gray.)

Comment: Can you please create a [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) on  [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/)?